# How to create a flower shape with ellipses within a class function?

Tags: javascript, class, p5.js

I'm trying to make a mini game in which a flower (made up of ellipses) is moved by the mouse horizontally in order to catch rain droplets.

I'm struggling with several different issues and would love some help!

My first issue is that I originally placed the daisy (ellipses) inside the `gameScreen` function. I'm trying to place it inside of a class instead, because that will make it easier to target. I'm new to classes and can't even figure out how to place an ellipse within it, much less several. My attempt to put it into a class is called "daisy" in the code below. I can't get it to show up.

My second issue is making the game not end as soon as you miss one droplet. I would like it to end after missing 3, but can't figure it out what I need to change to do this.

And finally, my third issue would be making the color change to a darker and darker brown as the water droplets are missed.

Any help with any of these issues would be greatly appreciated! I've been trying to figure it out for days with no luck.

[Original code snippet source](https://editor.p5js.org/mvaquerano/sketches/_11YvYDei) shown below:

```js
let screen = 0;
let score= 0;
let drop1;
let drop2;
let drop3;



function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  drop1 = new rdrop1(70);
  drop2 = new rdrop1(50);
  drop3 = new rdrop1(25);
 
}

function draw() {

  if(screen == 0){
    startScreen();
  }
  
  else if(screen == 1){
    gameScreen();
  }
}

function startScreen(){
  background(9, 143, 18);
  fill(255);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textSize(40);
  text('water the daisy', width / 2, height / 2);
  textSize(20);
  text('click to start', width / 2, height / 2 + 40);
    reset();
}

function gameScreen(){
  background(9, 143, 18);
  text("score = " + score, 50,25);
  noStroke();
  //flower
  fill(240, 252, 243);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  // ellipse(mouseX+25,height-50,50,50);
  ellipse(mouseX-25,height-50,50,50);
  ellipse(mouseX,height-75,50,50);
  ellipse(mouseX,height-25,50,50);
  fill(235, 216, 52);
  ellipse(mouseX,height-50,30,30);
  
  drop1.update();
  drop1.render();
  drop2.update();
  drop2.render();
  drop3.update();
  drop3.render();
  
  if(drop1.y>height){
    screen =2;
     }
  if(drop2.y>height){
    screen =2;
  }
  if(drop3.y>height){
    screen =2;
  }
  
  fill(255);
  if(drop1.y>height-75 && drop1.x>mouseX-20 && drop1.x<mouseX+20){
    score+= 1;
    drop1.reset();
  }
  if(drop2.y>height-75 && drop2.x>mouseX-20 && drop2.x<mouseX+20){
    score+= 1;
    drop2.reset();
  }
  if(drop3.y>height-75 && drop3.x>mouseX-20 && drop3.x<mouseX+20){
    score+= 1;
    drop3.reset();
  }
}



function mousePressed(){
  if(screen==0){
    screen=1;
  }
  else if(screen==2){
    screen=0;
  }
}

function reset(){
  score=0;
  drop1.speed=0.8;
  drop1.y=-10;
  drop2.speed=0.8;
  drop2.y=-10;
  drop3.speed=0.8;
  drop3.y=-10;
}

class rdrop1{
  
  constructor(size){
    this.y = -10;
    this.x = random(20,width-20);
    this.size = size;
    this.speed = 2;
  }
  
  update(){
    this.y += this.speed
    
  }
  
  render(){
  
    fill(7,179,223);
    ellipse(this.x,this.y,this.size,this.size);
  }
  
  reset(){
    this.y = -10
    this.x = random(20,width-20)
    this.speed+= 0.2
  }
  // reduceLife(){
  // this.lifespan-=0.5
  // }
}

class daisy{
  constructor(xpos,ypos) {
    this.x = mouseX+25;
    this.y = height-50;
    this.diameter = 50;
  }
  
  render(){ 
    let c = map(rdrop1, 0, width, 0, 255);
     if(this.lifespan===0){
       fill (54, 32, 10)
     }
    fill (255, 253, 252)
    ellipse(this.x,this.y,this.diameter);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js" crossorigin=""></script>
```

Comment: I've only ever worked on p5js and the code I posted is exactly what I'm working on. I can't figure out why stack overflow doesn't think it's formatted correctly, so I just added the link to my sketch so you can check out a working example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code a bit so it has the added features. The `daisy` class has a `health` variable which decreases whenever it misses a rain drop. Also, when this happens, its color gets darker.

I have added a `gameSettings` variable to hold all the data about the game. The advantages to this are: you can easily modify the attributes - for example to have difficulty levels. Also, it removes "magic" numbers - hard coded values in the main game code.

```js
var gameSettings = {
  canvasSize: {
    width: 600,
    height: 400
  },
  numRainDrops: 3,
  initialSpeed: 2,
  speedUp: 0.4,
  daisyDiameter: 40,
  daisyMaxHealth: 3,
  minRainDropSize: 25,
  maxRainDropSize: 75,
  backgroundColor: "rgb(9, 143, 18)",
  rainDropColor: "rgb(7, 179, 223)",
  daisyColor: "rgb(235, 216, 52)",
  textColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
};

// Helper class to find intersections of circles.
// Can be improved for better accuracy
class boundingBox {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    // Move x,y from center of circle to top,left of box
    this.x = x - w / 2;
    this.y = y - h / 2;
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
  }

  intersectsWith(other) {
    return (Math.abs((this.x + this.width / 2) - (other.x + other.width / 2)) * 2 < (this.width + other.width)) &&
      (Math.abs((this.y + this.height / 2) - (other.y + other.height / 2)) * 2 < (this.height + other.height));
  }
}

class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.gameStatus = "start";
    this.reset();
  }

  reset(width, height) {
    // An array of raindrops - not hard-coded to 3
    this.drops = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < gameSettings.numRainDrops; i++) {
      this.drops.push(new rainDrop(map(random(), 0, 1, gameSettings.minRainDropSize, gameSettings.maxRainDropSize)));
    }
    this.daisy = new daisy(gameSettings.daisyDiameter);
    this.score = 0;
  }

  startGame() {
    this.gameStatus = "running";
  }

  draw() {
    if (this.gameStatus === "start") {
      this.startScreen();
    }
    else if (this.gameStatus === "running") {
      this.gameScreen();
    }
  }

  startScreen() {
    background(gameSettings.backgroundColor);
    fill(gameSettings.textColor);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    textSize(40);
    text('water the daisy', width / 2, height / 2);
    textSize(20);
    text('click to start', width / 2, height / 2 + 40);
  }

  // Main game loop
  gameScreen() {
    background(gameSettings.backgroundColor);
    this.daisy.draw();

    // Draw each raindrop and check if it hits the daisy
    for (let drop of this.drops) {
      drop.updateAndRender();
      if (drop.boundingBox.intersectsWith(this.daisy.boundingBox)) {
        this.score += 1;
        drop.top();
      }
      else if (drop.isOffScreen()) {
        drop.top();
        this.daisy.health -= 1;
      }
    }

    fill(gameSettings.textColor);
    text("score = " + this.score, 50, 25);
  }

  isGameOver() {
    // Check for game over - daisy health is 0
    if (this.daisy.health <= 0) {
      this.gameStatus = "stopped";
      return true;
    }
  }
}

class rainDrop {
  constructor(size) {
    this.size = size;
    this.y = -10;
    this.x = random(20, width - 20);
    this.speed = gameSettings.initialSpeed;
  }

  // Move back to top
  top() {
    this.y = -10;
    this.x = random(20, width - 20);
    this.speed += gameSettings.speedUp;
  }

  // Return this raindrops box
  get boundingBox() {
    return new boundingBox(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
  }

  updateAndRender() {
    this.y += this.speed;
    fill(gameSettings.rainDropColor);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
  }

  isOffScreen() {
    return this.y >= height;
  }
}

class daisy {
  constructor(d) {
    this.diameter = d;
    this.center = {
      x: mouseX + 25,
      y: height - this.diameter
    };
    this.health = gameSettings.daisyMaxHealth;
  }

  get boundingBox() {
    return new boundingBox(this.center.x, this.center.y, this.diameter, this.diameter);
  }

  draw() {
    noStroke();
    ellipseMode(CENTER);

    // Petal color - the lower our health, the darker the petal
    const color = map(this.health, 0, gameSettings.daisyMaxHealth, 0, 255);
    fill(color, color, color);

    // Draw petals
    this.center.x = mouseX;
    ellipse(this.center.x, this.center.y - this.diameter / 2, this.diameter, this.diameter);
    ellipse(this.center.x, this.center.y + this.diameter / 2, this.diameter, this.diameter);
    ellipse(this.center.x - this.diameter / 2, this.center.y, this.diameter, this.diameter);
    ellipse(this.center.x + this.diameter / 2, this.center.y, this.diameter, this.diameter);

    // Draw center
    fill(gameSettings.daisyColor);
    ellipse(this.center.x, this.center.y, this.diameter * .7, this.diameter * .7);
  }
}

let game;

// Initialize
function setup() {
  createCanvas(gameSettings.canvasSize.width, gameSettings.canvasSize.height);
  game = new Game();
}

function draw() {
  game.draw();
  if (game.isGameOver()) {
    game.reset();
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (game.gameStatus !== "running") {
    game.startGame();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
```